# Which would be correct amount is refunded or refund is made?

Tags: word-choice, tense

**I want to say:**

> As per the client's request, the order is cancelled and a **refund is made.**
> **or**
> As per the client's request, the order is cancelled and the **amount is refunded.**

Which one is correct?

Comment: I don't think the best tense has been used in these examples.    "... the order has been cancelled and a refund has been made".

Comment: @JamesK Thank you, may I know what would be wrong with the present tense?

Comment: The action of cancelling the order occurred in the past. The consequence of that past event in in the present.  So present perfect is a natural tense to use.

Comment: Thank you @JamesK , why don't you answer so I can accept and appreciate it. Thanks for your time and efforts.

Comment: Because I haven't answered your question...  You didn't ask if the tense was correct. You asked if refund should be used as a noun or verb.

Comment: @JamesK Then you can answer both sentences that are wrong cause of tense. **The action of cancelling the order occurred in the past. The consequence of that past event in in the present. So present perfect is a natural tense to use.**

Comment: @JamesK I've added **tense** tag. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct.

refund (noun)- A refund is given/ offered. I am offered/given a refund.

refund (transitive verb)- The money is refunded.

past- A refund was given/offered. I was given/offered a refund.

past- The money was refunded.

Answer (score 2):

PAST TENSE:

As per the **client's request**, the order **was** cancelled and the amount **was** refunded. [specifically]

COMPARE:

As per a client's request, the order is cancelled and the amount is refunded. [in general]